# spring.session.timeout vs server.servlet.session.timeout

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, application.properties

I'm looking to extend the user session in a Spring MVC app with Spring boot and Tomcat. Looking at the documentation there seems to be 2 relevant [properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html):

```
server.servlet.session.timeout
spring.session.timeout
```

Most examples out there seem to suggest to use `server.servlet.session.timeout`; what is the purpose of `spring.session.timeout`? Which one should be used to extend the user session?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`spring.session.timeout` is the property from a Spring sub-project called [`Spring Session`](https://spring.io/projects/spring-session). It will fallback to `server.servlet.session.timeout` if it is not set.

In short , Spring Session allows you to store HttpSession in RDBMS / Redis / Hazelcast Cluster / MongoDB rather than an internal map inside Tomcat .So the sessions is stored in the container agnostic way and make session clustering easier as you do not need to configure a Tomcat cluster.

So if you do not use `Spring Session` , you should use `server.servlet.session.timeout`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set the **server.session.timeout** in your application.properties file to do the same

I think, If you add **spring.session.timeout** in application.properties the session timeout value mentioned using **server.session.timeout** will be overridden